# Read multiple values in one line with Lua

Tags: lua

How can I read more than one variable on the same line using Lua?
something like this line in python:

```py
x, y = input().split()
```

Comment: Lua comes with a manual btw...  [Chapter 3.4 Expressions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4)

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how you'd do in Lua, assuming the function returns multiple results in its `return` statement:

```
function foo() return 2, 1 end
local x, y = foo()
print(x, y) -- prints 2, 1
```